How to render an image with a border with an hardware accelerated API
What is the go-to strategy for rendering an image with a border with hardware accelerated API:s?
Algorithm 1:

Draw the image using a textured quad
Draw the border using a textured quad of the same size as the first one, and using the alpha channel for pixels that are within the border

Algorithm 2:

Draw the image using a textured quad
Use a second mesh, that only has content surrounding the first quad (see image), thus filling less pixels, but at the cost of using more polygons, and also additional pipeline re-configurations.


Assume that the image can be as large as a regular computer display.
